# If a Dyson Sphere from the Star Trek universe could move, would the star inside also move or would it collide with the sphere's inner surface?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, dyson-sphere

Like the ones in TNG "Relics" or STO's Solanae/Jenolan Spheres. Going by the principle that something suspended inside a speeding bus doesn't automatically collide with the back end, would the same apply here?

Comment: The star isn't exactly contained within the sphere as much as the sphere is anchored to the star. To move the whole construct, the real challenge would be moving the star without destroying the sphere. See "Bowl of Heaven" by Larry Niven & Gregory Benford for one take on how that might look.

Comment: Just a thought, but you might want to read [Bowl of Heaven](http://amzn.com/0765366460).  It is about a partial sphere that moves around with its Star.  I am not sure how accurate the physics are though.

Comment: Although interesting, this question doesn't actually seem to be about the in-universe Dyson sphere.

Comment: Unless this actually happened somewhere in the _Star Trek_ universe, any attempt at an answer would be pure speculation, which is not what this stack is about. You could try asking over on the [World Building Stack](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), this seems up their alley.

Comment: Actually, the question is not about _Star Trek_ at all, it just uses that as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: As @John Meachem points out, I got the physics at the end wrong and thus reached the wrong conclusion. I have ripped out the wrong parts and updated accordingly. Oops :)

---

We've never seen anyone on *Star Trek* try this, so we don't really know. And Dyson spheres are probably impossible in reality (at least, impossible to make habitable), so we can't just try it and see. However, based on the general theory behind them, we can imagine what would happen if someone did try to move such a sphere.

First of all, your moving-bus analogy breaks down for two reasons:

- Objects in a moving bus don't hit the back window because the objects are moving at the same velocity as the bus. If the bus accelerated rapidly, any free-floating objects *would* collide with the back.
- Objects that accelerate and decelerate along with the bus do so because something pushes on them: either the bus itself (through friction, direct contact, etc.) or the air inside the bus.

A Dyson sphere, on the other hand, is floating in space, with no "atmosphere" between it and the star. (A habital sphere, like the ones shown on Star Trek, likely have a small atmosphere on the inner surface, but it wouldn't be very significant.) The sphere and the star are not moving relative to each other; in other words, they're both moving in the same speed and direction relative to the other objects in their vicinity. But, like a moving vehicle, if one of those things suddenly accelerates, it won't cause the other to do so.

The only force that the sphere might exert on the star from the distances in question would be gravity. However, as pointed out in the comments, it has been shown that -- asusming the Dyson sphere was completely symmetrical -- it would have a net zero gravitational effect on objects inside, [no matter where they are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem). This means, moving the sphere would have no effect at all on the star.

This is actually an issue that any Dyson sphere would have to deal with on a constant basis. It's going to be continuously bombarded by external objects (meteorites, etc.) slamming into it from the outside. Any such will accelerate the sphere, and eventually it will [drift into the star.](http://www.aleph.se/Nada/dysonFAQ.html#STABLE) It would require constant course corrections to keep the sphere in place where it needs to be.

Comment: Great answer :) The Dyson Sphere's in question do have "air" inside them but no extending all the way to the star, think it's more like a regular planetary atmosphere covering the entirety of the inside surface (see here http://i.imgur.com/gqcmSsW.jpg looking down at the atmosphere and weather system from above, and here http://i.imgur.com/x2wo498.jpg looking up from the same spot at the star and other side of the sphere), most likely doesn't change anything. But it's a mind melter to think about!

Comment: Star trek books and the online game have had the Dyson spheres move

Comment: Note that a dyson sphere is not in orbit.It is held up by mechanical compression, not a balancing of gravitational and centrifugal forces. It is actually completely gravitationally isolated from the star within it due to the much lauded shell theorem of newton. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem So, there is no effect on the star no matter how slowly you move the sphere, the star will stay put.

Comment: huh, that's interesting. I hadn't really looked into the physcs of a sci-fi Dyson sphere much.. the original Dyson sphere wasn't a solid mass, but a bunch of separate orbital bits. I was mostly going by this: http://www.aleph.se/Nada/dysonFAQ.html#STABLE but I clearly misunderstood it :)

Comment: Hmm. Since the Sphere encloses the star, there would be a balancing effect from the star's own gravity. Whacking it with an asteroid would have no effect

Comment: @richard that's what I originally thought but Newton says I'm wrong. Read the link about the shell theorum... As long as the Dyson sphere is symmetrical, the gravitational attraction between the star and the sphere is exactly equal no matter where the star is inside the sphere.  An asteroid would push the sphere but the gravitational pull of the star would not change so there would be no counterbalancing force on the sphere

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - I remain unconvinced. Sure the shell would seek equilibrium with the star precisely centred?

Comment: you would think that (as I did) but the math behind the shell theorum is clear. Regardless of where the star is inside the shell, the forces are identical. the star being in the center is no more "equilibrium" than any other configuration.

Comment: @Valorum Actually, that's exactly why a shell like this has been discredited soon after conception (what Dyson had in mind was actually a system of satellites freely orbitting the star, not a solid shell). The system isn't stable, and will quickly drift out of position and disrupt the star or the shell. Of course, this is only considering gravity - it's not clear how the radiative effects would work in a real system. A simplified static spherical model still shows a positive feedback loop - any disruption will grow *larger* over time.